# How to skip 4 items using CAML?

Tags: linq, caml

Is there a LINQ equivalent skip functionality in CAML.

I would like to skip the first 4 items in the list and display the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

see this example:

**C# version**

```
// this is an extension method type ofLINQ
int[] hello = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
var world = hello.Skip(4);

foreach (var n in world) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(n); 
}
```

it will display

```
5
6
```

and by the way, what language are you using? `C#` or `VB`? this is for `C#`

**Here's the VB Version**

```
Dim numbers() = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Dim allButFirst4Numbers = From n In numbers Skip 4
For Each n In allButFirst4Numbers
        Console.WriteLine(n)
Next
```

it will display

```
5
6
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I am using C# and CAML query to display a custom sharepoint web part. The code snippet you posted sure works for C# but I am looking for a way to filter the items out using CAML??